# Asking to delay the start date of employment due to Visa issues

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, new-job, visa, start-date

I was offered a job by a Engineering firm in the semiconductor area. Initially, the start date was supposed to be sometime 
in June. I had my H-1B Visa application in progress at that time and I asked them for an extension till October so that
once the visa is approved in October, we can transfer it to them and I can start working there.
They agreed to do that and since they had an urgent need, they did some internal workforce balancing to make up for my delayed joining.

But, the visa was still not approved by october and I asked for an extension of 3 weeks. They agreed to that
and asked me to get back to them by then. but from the current state of things, It appears unlikely that the
Visa will be approved by the time I would need to get back to them.

In this case, 
1) Will it be considered unprofessional/annoying if I ask once more for an extension considering 
the fact that they have already waited so long for me? This process is completely out of my hands and there
is nothing I can do to expidate this except ask my current lawyer and employer to do it fast.

2) Is it unreasonable to ask them for another 2 weeks time?

3) Is there any chance that they might accept my request third time or will the hiring manager be annoyed?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Will it be considered unprofessional/annoying if I ask once more
>   for an extension considering the fact that they have already waited so
>   long for me? This process is completely out of my hands and there is
>   nothing I can do to expidate this except ask my current lawyer and
>   employer to do it fast.
>
> 2) Is it unreasonable to ask them for another 2 weeks time?
>
> 3) Is there any chance that they might accept my request third time or
>   will the hiring manager be annoyed?

Companies that hire folks with Visa issues understand how these things happen.

Ask for whatever time your lawyer thinks you will actually need. If that's 2 weeks, then go with that. If your lawyer thinks you will need more than 2 weeks, then ask for that. You will be better served asking once, than asking for 2 weeks several more times. You might even have your lawyer draft a letter to the company explaining how much more time is needed and why.

It's possible that at some point the hiring manager will give up on you and need to move on to another candidate. But that's not within your control.

Ask for what you need and hope for the best.

Comment: Thank you @Joe, the issue was that my lawyer initially told me 3 weeks would be sufficient but now from the looks of it it seems like it is going to take another 2 weeks. 
Do they give out a final chance to decide or will they just rescind the offer (usually)?

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be considered unprofessional/annoying if I ask once more for an extension considering the fact that they have already waited so long for me?

This can be seen a bit unprofessional from your part as it seems you have done it several times now. Even though these things are somehow out of your hands you can still provide them more information about this process, so they are aware of the fact that it can actually be a long or unclear process.

> Is it unreasonable to ask them for another 2 weeks time?

Unreasonable perhaps not, but it would not be received so gladly for sure, and may even be a bit abusive on their trust and time put on the application.

What I suggest you do (and what yo should have done earlier) is to be really clear with them and tell them this process does not seem to have a *really clear* date. The problem is that you have repeatedly agreed on a date (that you estimated) and had to postpone it (thus making *you* miss that word you gave on the date).

Being honest and telling them that you are doing your best to speed the process can also help, so they can see you are indeed interested in the job (maybe forwarding them the several follow up emails you should have about your visa). It could even be that they may be able to help you in some way if you ask.

> Is there any chance that they might accept my request third time or will the hiring manager be annoyed?

This you can only know if you ask them. Usually people say that "third time's a charm", so probably a third time that you postpone the application may bee seen as something unprofessional. However, it may be that they are aware of this long process and are being more tolerant with you about it.

If it were me I would definitely doubt about your commitment and time management abilities if this happened a third time, so be sure to be really polite, receptive, and clear when/if you ask them a third time.

Comment: Thank you @GrayCygnus But considering the fact that I just relay the timeline that my lawyer tells me, will the wrong estimate of the timeline fall on me?

Comment: Glad to help @ntd welcome to The Workplace :) remember to upvote answers that you think are useful so other users may benefit from your question (not saying that you *should* but it something you can do). Feel free to comment on any follow up you have.

Comment: It doestn show my upvote, apparently I do not ahve 'reputation'. and yeah, I wanted to know that since I just relay the timeline that my lawyer tells me, will the wrong estimate of the time be seen as my mistake per se by the new employer?

Comment: @ntd well it is you who is seeking for a job. Even though your lawyer may be calculating that date it is you who is saying to your hiring manager, so in a way of speaking it is your reputation that is at stake if you repeatedly fail to commit to a date (again, it is you the one seeking the job)